# How to influence the width of a drop down list without changing the width of the colum that contains the list

Tags: excel

Let me explain my problem/title. I currently have a column with a question, for example:

You are part of what generation?

This column has a width of 50. Now for the answers I use a drop down list that contains certain answers. Example answer:

"Generation X (Generation X, or Gen X, is the demographic cohort following the baby boomers. There are no precise dates for when this cohort starts or ends; demographers and researchers typically use starting birth years ranging from the early-to-mid 1960s and ending birth years ranging from the late 1970s to early 1980s.)"

The problem I am having is that you can't read this text in the drop down list, because after a certain width ( a bit more than the 50 width of the column) it gets cut off. I would like to increase the width of the drop down list without influencing the column width.

Is this possible without using VBA? I tried influencing the width of column where the answers of the drop down list are located, but that didn't change anything. I also tried all kinds of format options, but again no luck.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance
(and just to be clear, my example answer length is an exaggeration of my problem)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a valid option, you can use the ActiveX ComboBox, available under the Developer tab.  The ComboBox has two properties:  Width, and ListWidth.  You can set ListWidth wider than your column width to achieve the desired effect.